# Jquery .text imprimindo somente uma vez

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.getScript("func2.js", function() {
    $(".teste1").text("1");
    $(".teste2").text("2");
});

<div class="teste1" style="color: red"><div>
<div class="teste2"><div>
```

Porque ele só inseri uma vez?

Answer (score 2):

Porque tem um erro no seu código, observe que tem uma virgula, remova ela que resolverá.

Remova essa virgula no final:

```
$(".teste1").text("1"),
```

Para:

```
$(".teste1").text("1");
```

Comment: Desculpe, editei a pergunta, o probelama é usando a função .getScript

Comment: @Josimara experimente fechar as divs.

Answer (score 1):

Tens 3 erros no teu código:

- falta fechar as divs com `/`
- falta o `{` na abertura da função
- deves usar `;` e não `,` para separar as linhas

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".teste1").text("1");
    $(".teste2").text("2");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="teste1" style="color: red"></div>
<div class="teste2"></div>
```

Comment: Não tinha percebido! Thanks :) o erro era no fechamento da div

Answer (score 1):

Coloquei seu código no `jsfiddle`, claro retirando o nome do script e funciona, apenas corrigindo as tags que estão erradas:

```
<div class="teste1" style="color: red"><div>
```

Deveria ser:

```
<div class="teste1" style="color: red"></div>
```

E

```
<div class="teste2"><div>
```

Deveria ser

```
<div class="teste2"></div>
```

Ou seja, as tag `div` não estão sendo fechadas

Comment: Não tinha percebido! Thanks :)